# Play 2.2.1 sub-projects vs sub-packages?

Tags: java, scala, routes, sbt, playframework-2.2

I know my question is a little weird ,but i will try to explain.

Me and other 8 programmers are working on the same project ( 2 teams ) ,
and each team has its own responsibilities , so we thought why not to split our play project to modules so each team can work on their module?

After search about play sub-project and sbt multi projects , we are afraid the benefit from this move is lower than the cost of setting every thing up (we already have a play project built on top of our infrastructure ).

So I have been thinking why not to just split our route file to multiple routes files with some how corresponding packages ?

In short , i would really appreciate a little review on the benefits of sub-projects and in which use case i should use them , because i found almost nothing on this on the web .

BTW , it's play java , although it does not matter that much in this case..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Some benefits from the top of my head:

- Faster compilation, sbt can compile just those modules that changed and can compile modules in parallel if the dependency tree allows for it
- Faster testing, same as with compilation
- Protection against accidental coupling between separate parts, if there is no dependencies between two submodules A and B there can be no accidental usage of classes from A in B
- When separating things into suprojects: Makes accidental tight coupling painfully visible (why on earth does User depend on Play cache???)
- Makes it possible to make parts of the code base totally decoupled from play, so that they can be used in any Scala project
- Future option of making any subproject a project/library with it's own lifecycle, for example integration projects that is written once and then almost never changes can be "released" to a corporate repository

Comment: First , thanks a lot for those points , I will consider them .
But i actually need the technical point of view of re-factoring an existing project (regular Play project) to multi-project which contains the original project as a module. Another thing that i would like to hear about your experience at is deploy Play multi-project to production. I saw that in production it creates JAR file for each sub-project and another "root" JAR file that I assume will use the others. Does it cost in performance? how hard is to maintain Play multi-project code and how the Eclipse IDE deals with it?

Comment: No problems building or deploying multimodule projects at all. I prefer not to have the root project produce anything but only aggregate, and then have a separate subproject that is the "end product". I have no idea about eclipse, works pretty good in Intellij, should be easy to create a toy multi module to test in your environment.